# SUM certain column in an array (Javscript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have very simple question, i am learning javascript.

I have this 2D array :-

```
let text = [[1,a],[2,b]]
```

And I want to sum the numeric values of array, I know how to do  it using for loop but is there any way to do in shorter way like we can do it using 1D array by using `reduce`?

If i have this array :-

```
let text = [1,2]
```

I can easily sum it in one line like this :-

```
text.reduce((a,b) =>  a + b)
```

Is there any way to do same way with 2d array too which also has string values.

Thanks

Comment: Just access the inner array's indices you want to sum: `text.reduce((a,b) =>  a[0] + b[0])`

Comment: I am getting an error `a is undefined`

Comment: That's because `a` and `b` you likely never declare. If you want those as a string, wrap each in quotes: `let text = [[1,"a"],[2,"b"]]`. Then in your `reduce`, `a[0]` + `b[0]` sums `1` and `2`.

Comment: @GetSet after one iteration `a` will be a number so `a[0]` will be undefined. Yevgen Gorbunkov's answer has a working version of this.

Comment: @BenStephens, `a[0]` *is* always number, if we are using the OP's example array. In the `reduce` it will always be the 1st index of the inner arrays.

Comment: @GetSet try `[[1], [2], [3]].reduce((a, b) =>  a[0] + b[0])` and then try `[[1], [2], [3]].reduce((a, b) =>  a + b[0], 0)` in the console.

Comment: Of course @BenStephens its possible to break the solution by using an input array the OP *didn't* state in the question. But then the point would be lost in steering/hinting to ankit_dot was headed in the right direction. Furthermore attempting to create a "generic" summation function with `reduce` to work with "any" array, is impossible. Requirements must be known on the input, and thus the OP's actual input applies.

Comment: @GetSet any array with more than two entries would break your solution I haven't chosen some wierd edge case here.

Comment: How Yevgen Gorbunkov's answer will work if array is large, and i don't know exactly where the number column exist, In my original array i've exactly same issue, i am using `indexOf` to find the pos of sum column  in array, so how can I dynamically put that in, thanks for taking time and discussing it. you guys are amazing:)

Comment: @BenStephens ahhh I see your point. Where `a` inside the reduce is not the array reference, but the accumulated value. And so the fix would be: `text.reduce((a,b) =>  a + b[0], 0)`

Comment: @GetSet yep, you've explained it better than I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight alternative to Yevgen Gorbunkov's answer.

```js
const src = [[1, 'a', 4], [2, 'b', 5], [3, 'c', 6]];

const sum_by_col = (arr, col) =>
  arr
    .map((row) => row[col]) // pull column into new array
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b); // reduce as normal

console.log(sum_by_col(src, 0));
console.log(sum_by_col(src, 2));
```

Comment: Looping twice (with `.map()` then with `.reduce()`) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov if performance is an issue, a for loop will probably be faster. I think doing it this way might be a bit easier to understand and possibly makes inserting things like filtering, or swapping out what you want the reduce to do easier. This is a trivial bit of code so it doesn't really matter and it's less obvious; but in general it feels better to me to compile the data that you want to act on and then act on it as separate steps.

Comment: Other than performance, unnecessary verbosity doesn't seem reasonable. Like I said, if you feel like more explicit extracting of particular subarray element. or some filtering, or whatever kind of processing for that metter is necessary, it can be done inside `.reduce()` body.

Answer (score 2):

You may use that same `Array.prototype.reduce()` slightly modified to build up a custom summarizing function that may accept source array and `col` variable indicating target column:

```js
const src = [[1,'a'],[2,'b']]

const sumByCol = (arr, col) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row[col], 0)
  
console.log(sumByCol(src,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, can you little explain how this is working, how can i change the column index like if i have large array, and numeric values to sum, somewhere in between, Like position 15 of array?

Comment: @ankit_dot the second argument to `sumByCol` should allow you to specify which column you're interested in. If in the above answer you had `const src = [[1, 'a', 4], [2, 'b', 5]]`, then `sumByCol(src,2)` would give you 9.

Comment: Minor nit pick: you don't need the assignment in the reducer function. i.e. `(acc, row) => acc+=row[col]` could be `(acc, row) => acc + row[col]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in a single line by doing this **:**

```js
let text = [[1,'a'],[2,'b']]

console.log(
  text.flat()
  .filter((item) => typeof item === 'number')
  .reduce((total, item) => total + item)
)
```

Comment: What is the `.sort()` doing here? It also seems like OP wants to sum a specific column within the 2d array, and not all columns/values within the inner array (based on the title)

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for pointing that out. I removed that sorting method as anyhow we are filtering with number type. Also, OP said he has 2D array and not a mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
let text = [[1,'a'],[2,'b']]
let numbers_only = text.flat().filter(x => Number(x))
let sum = numbers_only.reduce((a,b) => a + b)

//answer = 3
```

As a one-liner -

```
   let sum = text.flat().filter(x => Number(x)).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you little explain how this is working, how can i change the column index like if i have large array, and numeric values to sum, somewhere in between, Like position 15 of array? there can be more numeric column in an array

Comment: @Nick - You might want to change your filter condition, or convert `b` to a number before you add it, otherwise `[[1,'2'],[2,'b']]` would end up with `122`.

Comment: Good point @NickParsons ! cheers